# What does registerHTTPOperationClass in AFNetworking actually do?

Tags: objective-c, ios, http, afnetworking

I am trying to understand how the `AFNetworking` Framework works. But there is little detail I do not understand.

I wrote a subclass of `AFHTTPclient` than made it a singleton class and added a Initializer that does the following :

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I got this code from a tutorial I found on the internet, but I do not understand why I have to register my class for `JSONRequestOperation` if I want to get JSON Data back? What exactly happens under the hood if I am doing so? What does the `registerHTTPOperation` class exactly do?

PS: Is there a good documentation with examples and in-depth explanations of `AFNetworking` somewhere on the internet?

Comment: All the documentation is here: http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`registerHTTPOperationClass:`](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/registerHTTPOperationClass%3a) on [`AFHTTPclient`](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#overview) will use the class set to handle you request when using the getPath and postPath methods.

In your given example, the HTTPRequestOperation is set the the [`AFJSONRequestOperation`](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFJSONRequestOperation.html), which means that all request to the server will be done with an instance of [`AFJSONRequestOperation`](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFJSONRequestOperation.html). The [`AFJSONRequestOperation`](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFJSONRequestOperation.html) will try and parse the result from the server with the [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

If you server responds with XML you should set the HTTPRequestOperation to [`AFXMLRequestOperation`](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFXMLRequestOperation.html) for example.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. That is the explanation i was looking for.

Comment: For me it only works if I set `[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];` as well. Why do I have to set the defaultHeader AND register AFJSONRequestOperation?

Comment: @hashier They are different things, the `registerHTTPOperationClass:` set the class used to parse the response. In your case the server need to the header to tell it to return the response in `JSON`.

Comment: Ahh, okay with `setDefaultHeader` I tell the server to send json. I thought it (my) Server was replaying json anyway no matter what I put in the header request.

Comment: @hashier that totally depends on your server, some server requires you to tell them the response type and other do not. If a server only support `JSON` the more often you do not need to set the `Accept` header.